# How to build relationships in PowerBI , so that slicer filters will work correctly?

Tags: powerbi

I have question about relationships in power bi.
[example of model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lth2c.png)

There are tables:
Calendar + Fact Revenue(Fact table) + Plan Revenue + Customers(Fact table) + Country

The problem is that Plan Revenue doesn't have Customers ID , so if I make slicer filter by Country from Customer table it doesn't show correct Plan Revenue for each country. But if I make slicer filter by Country table, then it doesn't filter by dates to show fact revenue. I can not make relationship from Plan Revenue with Customers table, as each has many to many for Country.

Dates are in correct type, all relationships many to one, all are active.
Is there any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would have `Country` or `Country ID` in the `Fact Revenue` table, and then add a relationship to your `Country` table. This follows [Star Schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/star-schema).

Otherwise, you could add a relationship between your `Customers` table and your `Country` table, which would then make it a Snowflake schema.

Ask yourself if revenue follows a customer or where the transaction took place (think of customers with transactions in multiple countries). A Fact table is fact (doesn't change), so think about what if a Customer's country changes.
*(Nudging you to go for the first option.)*

---

You will also need to update the relationships between:

- `Calendar` and `Plan Revenue`
- `Country` and `Plan Revenue`

Both of these are `1-1` and as a result these are bi-directional, and therefore when you slice on `Country`, it will advertently also filter `Calendar` via `Plan Revenue`.

Update both of these to be:

- `Calendar` `1:*` `Plan Revenue` **Single** cross-filter
- `Country` `1:*` `Plan Revenue` **Single** cross-filter
  and also ensure the same for:
- `Country` `1:*` `Customer` **Single** cross-filter

Comment: Thank you, I tried as you said, but still doesn't work. In my situation customers country can not change, so I made relationship from Customer to Country, but if I make slicer filter from Country table, I am not able to choose dates from Calendar. It is strange for me, why doesn't it work. Dates are from Fact Revenue which is connected to Customers and Customers is connected to Country. ( It is working if I make slicer for country from Customers, but then it doesn't work for Plan Revenue

Comment: Updated answer with additional info at the bottom regarding your relationships being 1:1 both and need to change to 1:* single

Comment: Did the updated answer work out for you?